# How to check rode users laravel/ui

Tags: laravel, laravel-ui

What type of user do I want to check when I log in
If role is admin then redirect to admin page
If role is users then redirect to home page

I using laravel/ui latest version

Answer (score 0):

In `app\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php` you can do something like this:

```
public function redirectTo() {
  $role = auth()->user()->role; 
  switch ($role) {
    case 'admin':
      return '/admin_dashboard';
      break;
    case 'user':
      return '/user_dashboard';
      break; 

    default:
      return '/home'; 
    break;
  }
}
```

Make sure you remove the line of:
`protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`. In Laravel, you can either have `redirectTo` be a variable OR a function, but not both. By making it a function, you can redirect the user where they need to go based on their role.